# Blocking a website after two visits in the same day in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, blocking

How do I block myself from visiting a website after having already going to it twice before in the same day?

I'm trying to impose a self-block in Google Chrome, maybe an extension would help, where it would deny access to a particular website if I've already been x times already.

I just catch myself going to Facebook more than twice a day and this sadly happens with me not really being aware of it. Such an extension should help me curb those unnecessary visits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the Chrome Extension [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji) a try.

It doesn't restrict you based on visits but time spent on each site.  You can configure the time allowed for sites and also the time period in which StayFocusd operates i.e 9am - 5pm etc.

Comment: does similar thing exist for Safari?